# i can`t store session value passing through jquery ajax. in codeigniter php framework

Tags: php, codeigniter, jquery

I have a problem storing session value; 
I am not able to increment the session count variable 
via the AJAX Jquery call with some value passing
to function, also my previously set array which stores the session is change with a new one.

What is the problem here:

1>when i use one controller function

```
startOnlineTest($testid=0)
 i set session countnew as 0
$this->session->set_userdata('countnew',0);
  and in view i use jquery to pass data to other function of same controller
  public function ResponseOnline($qid,$response)
```

using change effect of jquery

```
 echo "[removed]$(document).ready(function(){";
         foreach($question['childQuestion'] as $q=>$aq){  // 
echo "\$(\"input:radio[name=qid-$q]\").live('change',function(){
var sr=\$(\"input:radio[name=qid-$q]:checked\").map(function() {
          return $(this).val();
          }).get().join(); 
       var qid = \$(\"input:radio[name=qid-$q]\").attr(\"qaid\");
       "; echo "\$.get('"; echo base_url();echo "testpapers/ResponseOnline/'+qid+'/'+sr,{},function(data)
 {\$('#res').html(data)});
 });";}
 echo"});[removed]" ;// this script is working fine
```

now the problem is this i get the session value overwrite by the current one although i 
use array  my code for ResponseOnline
 is

```
public function ResponseOnline($qid,$response)
  {
  echo "this" .$this->session->userdata('countnew'); // this is not echo as set above by function  startOnlineTest($testid=0)[/color]
     i set session countnew as
     $this->session->set_userdata('countnew',0)

 echo $d=$qid; // i know its no use but to save time as tested on $d

 $s=$response;

if($this->session->userdata('countnew')==0)   //  algo for this function i check the                                       
                                               //countnew session varaible   if 0 do this 
{                                                
$sc=$this->session->userdata('countnew');     // store the countnew variable
echo $sc=$sc+1;                               // increment the counter variable
$this->session->set_userdata('countnew',$sc);  // store it in session 
echo "this is incrementes session value";     
echo $this->session->userdata('countnew');
$r2[$d]=$s;                               // store array value $r2 with key $d and value $s
$this->session->set_userdata('res',$r2);  //set this array value in session 
}
else{                                  // if session countnew!=0 then do this
$r2=$this->session->userdata('res');  // first store $r2 as array return from session
 $r2[$d]=$s;                         //then add value to this array                      

 $this->session->set_userdata('res',$r2); // storing this array to session
}
echo '<pre>';
print_r($r2);       // printing the array


}
```

i get the result for say for first call is fine but for second call my value is overwrite session show `Array([32323]=>23))` if i pass function `(32323,23)` if i pass `(33,42)`
i get `Array([33]=>42)` my old value is destroyed.

Answer (score 0):

You should just probably use regular sessions in php because sessions in codeigniter will only allow you to store a single item. 
Something like this:

```
$_SESSION['item'][] = $array;
```

Or maybe you could still use CodeIgniter sessions by doing something like this:

```
$items = $this->session->userdata('items');
array_push($items, $new_item);
$this->session->set_userdata('items', $items);
```

If you want to define the keys as well:

```
$items = $this->session->userdata('items');
$items['your_key'] = $new_item; 
$this->session->set_userdata('items', $items);
```

Comment: but i want to add key as well as value. i mean i want to use assoc array. so how i can use array_push

Comment: edited my answer. You get the idea. Just customize the code further to match your needs.

Comment: thank you for your reply but  i use same code but get the same error i use this $r2=$this->session->userdata('res');  // first store $r2 as array return from session
 $r2[$d]=$s;                         //then add value to this array                      

 $this->session->set_userdata('res',$r2);